# replace nested fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

So, I have a pageView with two tabs (fragments). I want to replace the content of one tab for another fragment.

So, that's what I'm trying:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Fragment chatFragment = ChatFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.tab_chat_list_container, chatFragment).commit();
}
```

But nothing happens, when this code is executed, (already check on debug, it's does get called).

Answer (score 0):

Add `getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately did not work =/